# Check if a certain value is present in an associated cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I asked a question a few days ago about creating a dynamic list in excel that was solved but now I am trying create another dynamic list that will trigger a flag when a specific value is associated to a cell.

For a step by step explanation of my problem,

1. The first column will be a room number and the second column will be a specific deficiency that occurs in that room.
2. The first row will repeat the room name until all deficiencies are listed in that specific room
3. When all the deficiencies are listed and the next room number is added in the first column it will update the formula created to automatically sum up the cost of all those deficiencies by room name.

The sheet looks like this currently:

[image]

Now the next problem I need is that whenever a room has a certain list of SPECIFIC deficiencies I need it to trigger in side a new column saying which rooms meet that criteria. For example if room 112 has 10.12, 10.13, and 10.14 then that would make column K on the right automatically update to list room 112 by name. This would be dynamic like how I have the cost estimate per room right now but not sure how to write the IF function to determine what value to make it appear. The current function I have right now doesn't work but excel if statements don't allow for multiple checks at least from what I've read. my current function is

`=VSTACK("Room No", LET(x,A4:Index(A4:A5000,COUNTA(A4:A5000)), IF(UNIQUE(X)=10.12,UNIQUE(x),"")))`

This function only checks for if the unique value is equal to specifically 10.12 which I know won't work but I don't know how to have it check if the room name involves multiple deficiencies that are associated with it.The expected result would look something like this

[image]

Any input for how this formula should be adjusted would be very helpful or even an explanation of how this could be done would be more insightful.

Comment: It would help if you show us the expected result - currently column K is not visible in your screenshot

Comment: You have identified column A to be your x range in the IF statement, but in your IF formula, you are asking if unique values in column A (x) are equal to 10.12. The number 10.12 (and others) is in column B, not A.